# Issue with CodePen and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a simple page the displays random quotes from [QuotesOnDesign](http://quotesondesign.com/api-v4-0/) API. However, my "New Quote" element when clicked doesn't trigger the `getQuote` function. Here is a link to my code:

[CodePen Random Quote](http://codepen.io/nalexiou/pen/OVERjR/)

I suspect this is related to jQuery as the Chrome console displays an error mentioned that it refused to load script (referring to jQuery). The strange thing is that when I click on "New Quote" while I have the Developer Tools open in Chrome, it works!

Comment: i see no such errors (or any errors at all) in my developer console, although the button still seems to do nothing.

Comment: the event is triggering. i added `console.log('test');` lines to the start of both functions and both caused output on the console when i click the button.

Comment: I think the browser is caching the response. Opening the console makes it work because you have the DevTools option to disable the cache when debugging.

Comment: Add a cachebuster to the URL.

Comment: thanks Woodrow. I also verified that the click event gets triggered. There must something off with the  `.getJSON` call to the API. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser is caching the response the first time you call the API, and reusing that response on future calls. You can resolve this by adding a cachebuster to the URL.

The reason it works when you open the console is because you presumably have the **Disable cache (while DevTools is open)** option set.

```
function getQuote() {
  var cb = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
  $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=" + cb, function(a) {
    $(".quote-text").html(a[0].content + "<p>— " + a[0].title + "</p>");
  });
}
```

[Working CodePen](http://codepen.io/barmar/pen/PqagNw)

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of the funciton call altogether and give `$.ajax` a try like so:

```
$(".button").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
      url: 'http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1',
      success: function(a) {
        $(".quote-text").html(a[0].content + "<p>— " + a[0].title + "</p>")
      },
      cache: false
   });
});
```

With `cache: false` you are preventing caching on a per call basis so the content changes each time the button is clicked as expected.

Comment: The important part is `cache: false`, you should mention that in the answer.